# How can I get the 32 bit stack limits / the 32 bit TEB/TIB from an existing 32 bit process under windows in x64 mode?

Tags: debugging, winapi, wow64

Normally I would just cheat and use NtQueryInformationThread for ThreadBasicInformation
to get the TebBaseAddress

but wow64 threads have two stacks, this will only get the 64 bit Teb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best way I've found is to get the 32 bit context ( not via GetThreadContext, but Wow64GetThreadContext) and use Wow64GetThreadSelectorEntry to get the address of FS[0] and then use ReadProcessMemory. But the biggest problem is that this requires Win7/Windows2008 Server R2 )

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Windows debugging interface to attach to the process?  If so, you should be able to use the lpThreadLocalBase field of the events CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_INFO and CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_INFO to get the TEB base address when a new thread is created.

But I think this only works if your debugger has controlled the process from its creation.  This wouldn't help for attaching to an existing process.

Comment: Yes this is for existing processes, but that is a good point.  Other people may find that satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

This is an easier, albeit undocumented, method: http://redplait.blogspot.ru/2012/12/teb32-of-wow64-process.html

Comment: seems valid, Personally  I prefer:
http://www.dumpanalysis.org/blog/index.php/2010/10/08/raw-stack-dump-of-all-threads-part-4/